# Kafka returning Offset as 0 on Producing

Tags: go, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

Having written a basic channel based producer in golang using [confluent-kafka-go](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go) and a single partition single broker kafka set up through confluent.
On producing sometimes during iteration through the `acks`  the offset of the successfully produced message is received as **0**.

Sample logs :

> {"level":"info","msg":"Published successfully to topic test, offset 0, Partition 0 and Length 1316","time":"2017-10-03T17:03:43+05:30"}
>
> {"level":"info","msg":"Published successfully to topic test, offset 0, Partition 0 and Length 1316","time":"2017-10-03T17:03:43+05:30"}

This is the function that iterates over the kafka acks :

```
func (kc *KafkaClient) HandleAcknowledgements() {
  for event := range kc.AckChannel {
    message := event.(*kafka.Message)

    if message.TopicPartition.Error != nil {
      log.Errorf("Delivery Failed: Partition: %d Reason: %v", message.TopicPartition.Partition, message.TopicPartition.Error)
    } else {
      if message.TopicPartition.Offset == 0 {
        bodyLen := len(message.Value)
        log.Infof("Published successfully to topic %s, offset %s, Partition %d and Length %d", *message.TopicPartition.Topic, message.TopicPartition.Offset, message.TopicPartition.Partition, bodyLen)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My retention policy is as below :

```
   log.retention.hours=168
```

Any sort of help will be great, so as to why this happens !

Thanks.

Comment: not sure about that client that's just a wrapper on top of the C client, have you tried this one https://github.com/Shopify/sarama ?

Comment: Yes I did try that out to replicate this behaviour, probably this issue has something to do with the particular library itself. I noticed that, the messages are getting produced and the offset is maintained correctly internally, its just that the offset is not being reflected in the acks at times. Need to dig deeper to know the actual reason. Will update the post once I come across something concrete !  Thanks @YandryPozo !

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `produce.offset.report` to true in config.

> Try setting produce.offset.report to true for the producer, otherwise
>   it will only report the offset of the last message in each
>   batch/messageSet.
>
> The go client should really do this by default.

https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/issues/95#issuecomment-330837647

If this does not solve your problem, could you post the code and config you use for producing ?